# Rental unit ceiling, unsure if this was a previous repair or current unresolved leak

Tags: drywall, ceiling, leak

Just signed the lease on this place when I notice a suspicious looking spot on the ceiling.
It is only really visible at this angle, no dark spots or damp smell. The ceiling in that area looks just slightly dipped, but it's so small it could just be my imagination.

Should I be worried?

The landlord doesn't seem to know anything about it, how do I determine if this will cause me grief (or potentially have mold underneath) or if it can be not my problem for the year I'll be living here?

[image: Image of ceiling]

Comment: Not everybody can see the links when they're not properly formatted. Sure, it may work for some people but it won't appear as a link for those who can't get access to imgur.com for whatever reason. Not following the standard [diy.se] rules for formatting a link breaks things for some people. As does not using the default image hosting service.

Comment: It is hard to tell, but would get it in writing that the landlord does know about it.

Comment: What is directly above that location?  it does look like a repair and repaint was done, but without knowing what's above it, it's hard to tell if it's a one-time thing, or something that may need attention.  But as @crip659 indicated, it's best to get the landlord to acknowledge the current condition at move-in.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll definitely get it in writing. I believe the upstairs tenant's washer and drier is actually right above that area, which would make sense if there was a leak in their system. The question of whether it was one-time or continuous still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a rental, I wouldn't worry about it except to get a written statement from the landlord that it isn't your fault and to keep the area directly under it free if either electrical devices or breakables just in case.

It's the landlord's problem to deal with, not yours.

And odds are good that their way of dealing with it, unless it's getting worse, will just be to hide it under fresh paint.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah it is very much a landlord problem, my only concerns would be potential mold/health related if there's a lot of moisture up there.

Comment: If it isn't getting worse, don't worry about it.